# Setting linear gradient height AND width

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I am aware that you can set the width of a linear gradient using

```
    .grey-block { background: linear-gradient(to right, #f9f9f9 0%, #f9f9f9 35%, white 35%, white 100%); }
```

As well as the height

```
    .grey-block { background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f9f9f9 0%, #f9f9f9 65%, white 65%, white 100%); }
```

However, is there a way you can set BOTH the height and the width using a the same css line?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/. I'm not sure how you can have a gradient in two directions though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify, the code in the question is **not** setting the `height` and `width` of the gradient. It's adjusting the color stops, which results in a grey rectangle.

In order to adjust the actual dimensions of the gradient, we need to use the `background-size` property (as well as `background-repeat`) to set the `height` and `width` of the gradient.

With `background-size` in control of the gradient's dimensions, we can rewrite the CSS to be as follows:

```
.grey-block {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #f9f9f9);
  background-size: 35% 65%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

What's happening is that we're defining a "gradient" of a solid color and confining it's size. The `background-repeat` is disabled so that it will only render a single grey block.

```css
.grey-block {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #f9f9f9);
  background-size: 35% 65%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


/* non-relevant styles */
body {
  background-color: #222;
}
.grey-block {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grey-block"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an angle. That should do the trick.

```
.grey-block { background: linear-gradient( 135deg, #f9f9f9 0%, #f9f9f9 65%, white 65%, white 100%); }
```